# Introduce ZXing inside another activity (without opening a new activity)

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, barcode, zxing

I wanted to know if it was possible to introduce the ZXing scanning inside another activity. That would consist in having the main activity and inside it, in the bottom of the screen, I wanted to have a little window were the image captured by the camera would be shown.

Image example of what I want to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fncRQ.png

Currently I am executing the ZXing scanner by pressing a button; when pressed a new activity is opened in full-screen mode. When something is scanned, the applications returns to the main activity. However, as I commented, I would like to integrate the camera preview inside the Main Activity.

I found some information in the following blog http://gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/tag/accurate-image/ (GitHub link inside the blog) but it is not helping me since it does not work well and lots of exceptions are thrown continuously.

Is there any way I could use to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "it does not work well and lots of exceptions are thrown continuously" -- we cannot help you without code, details of what "does not work well" means, and stack traces about what exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: It is true that I have not explained well my problem... The fact is that what interests me the most is how to introduce a little window inside the main activity which contained the image being captured by the camera: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fncRQ.png .

Is it possible to do it? I have seen many ways to do it by Intent (that is, by opening a new activity), but I want to introduce it in the main activity not in full-screen mode. Ignore the github code because it adds extra functionality that will not work well until I complete the mini-camera-preview.

Thanks!